# Laravel5 get all result after 1000 row

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i am migrating Database in which i migration first 1000 rows but problem is that i need all the data after id = 1000 i am not getting the exact result. Please see my query

**Tried 1**

```
$count = oldo::count();
    $skip = 1000;
    $limit = $count - $skip; // the limit

    $oldOrder = oldo::skip($skip)->take($limit)->orderby('Std_ID')->paginate(500);
```

**Tried 2** 
$oldOrder = oldo::skip(1000)->orderby('Std_ID')->paginate(500);

PS:
Some rows are delete i need data via Primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do the following:

```
<?php
$oldOrder = oldo::where('Std_ID', '>', 1000)->paginate(500);
```

This way you select all orders where the ID is more than 1000